# Excluding jobs that haven't run recently from a view in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

Is it possible in Jenkins to exclude jobs from a view if they have not run recently?

I would like our default view to exclude jobs that have not run in the past month, because we don't need to see jobs from parts of the product that are not under active development.

There is a "Most recent jobs filter" in the View jobs filter plugin, but that wants me to specify a number of jobs to show.  I want to exclude by age, and not just show the most recent N.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried [the latest version of that plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/View+Job+Filters)? The following works for me to exclude old projects from a view:

[image]